# How did Kraglin end up with Yondu Udonta's prototype fin?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

We saw Quill give Kraglin Yondu's repaired arrow, and we saw Yondu's funeral during which Yondu was wearing his prototype fin as he seemed to disolve into bright bits of color and streamed into the void.

We know how he ended up with the arrow.
How did Kraglin end up with Yondu Udonta's prototype fin?

Comment: Seems there is only a question on [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73271/where-did-kraglin-get-a-fin-from) and not on S&F.

Comment: I assumed there was a second prototype fin, maybe Yondu had a whole collection of them in storage . . .

Answer (score 6):

## He was given a "version" of it

> **CREDIT BREAK 1 - INT. ECLECTOR HALLWAY - OUTER SPACE**
>
> *SURRENDER is PLAYING HERE. **Kraglin has had a version of Yondu’s fin implanted in his head.** He looks nervously down at the arrow on the floor.*
>
> *He tries to WHISTLE. It just flips around like a dead fish.*
>
> *He WHISTLES again, and it FLIES UP, hitting a wall, and falls back down again.*
>
> *He WHISTLES again, and it ZIPS AWAY. We HEAR A SCREAM.*
>
> *Kraglin looks around the corner where Drax is sitting, the ARROW IMPALED in his chest, yelling in agony.*
>
> *Kraglin looks around, hoping no one saw him there, and he tries to slink away.*
>
> <sub>[*Guardians Of The Galaxy Vol. 2* - The Official Script](https://web.archive.org/web/20171121231203/https://waltdisneystudiosawards.com/media/scripts/GotG2.pdf)</sub>

James Gunn has also mentioned on Twitter that the fin is different to Yondu's.

> Guardians Incredibly Frequently Asked Questions -
>   -Kraglin's fin at the end of Vol 2 is a different fin than Yondu's.
>   -Yes, I pick all the songs for the movies.
>   -The Guardians can travel light years in space, OF COURSE they can figure out how to power a Walkman/Zune w/o batteries
>
> <sub>[Twitter, @JamesGunn](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/994289874927669250)</sub>

No mention is made of where the fin came from in the script but there are likely two options:

- Yondu had another fin laying around somewhere like he had the prototype one in his draw
- Rocket created one from the prototype that was on Yondu's head

However, I think the latter is more likely, the main reason being why have Groot fetch the prototype fin from such a risky location if there were others on the ship?

We also know that Rocket is a very skilled mechanic/engineer and has had exposure to the fin and arrow already so has some idea how they work. Therefore, it is likely he could have created one for Kraglin.

> **INT. ECLECTOR HALLWAY/CELL - OUTER SPACE**
>
> *TWO RAVAGERS outside the cell hear the MUSIC. They turn, unlocking the cell door.*
>
> *As they enter, THE CAMERA OVERTAKES them, arriving before they do at --*
>
> *Yondu, sitting calmly; **Rocket is finishing ATTACHING THE BIGASS FIN TO HIS HEAD.** Its electrical systems POP on.*
>
> *PUSH IN ON the two surprised Ravagers trying to UNHOLSTER THEIR PISTOLS in time.*
>
> *Too late.*
>
> *Yondu WHISTLES.*
>
> [...]
>
> **QUILL:** Wait.
>
> *Quill holds out Yondu’s arrow. Kraglin’s lip trembles.*
>
> **QUILL:** *(CONT’D)* **Rocket grabbed the pieces and reassembled them.** I think Yondu would want you to have it.
>
> **KRAGLIN:** Thank you... Cap’n.
>
> <sub>[*Guardians Of The Galaxy Vol. 2* - The Official Script](https://web.archive.org/web/20171121231203/https://waltdisneystudiosawards.com/media/scripts/GotG2.pdf)</sub>